# Remote folder access on Linux

Tags: fedora, remote

In my school I have a fedora system running without root rights. At home I have a pc with root rights. Because the memory on school's fedora is for me not enough and I want to share some things between them, I want to make a folder on my home pc, so I can access it in my school.

I thought of sshfs and it was going to be easy, but I can't install it on  the school's system, cus of no root rights.

Could you help me?

Comment: Installing `sshfs` without root is tricky, because it requires kernel modules and the user to have FUSE permissions. It would probably be easier to copy files manually using an ordinary SFTP client.

Comment: Use `scp` or `rsync` or `ssh` directly to copy files..

Answer (score 2):

First thing should be asking somebody who has the root access if he can install it for you. It would solve all the problem and installing official package should not be against any regulation.

If it doesn't work, there is feature in **Nautilus** (file browser) to connect to server. I am not sure what backend does it use, but it should work without  any additions to default installation. It can use also SFTP protocol.